# Can a certain subset of $\mathbb{N}$ be written as an intersection of subsets with natural densities?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The natural density of a set $S$ of natural numbers is defined to be
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\#(S \cap \{1, 2, \cdots, n\})}{n},
$$
provided the limit exists.

Consider the set of natural numbers whose leading digit is $1$.

Its natural density does not exist (consider numbers of the form $2\cdot10^N$ and powers of $10$). Can this set be written as the intersection of two sets whose natural densities do exist?

Comment: I don't have the full answer, but here is one observation: if $A$ and $B$ each have a natural density while $A \cap B$ does not, then $A \cup B$ must also not have a natural density. More generally, If any three of these sets has a natural density, then the fourth must also, due to the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Why the analytic number theory tag? If this is number theory at all, it's elementary number theory, isn't it?

Comment: thanks for your answer! was going to put the elementary number theory tag but it seems to be limited to elementary algebraic techniques. I looked for a while and put analytic number theory the gave up :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $S$ be the set of all natural numbers with leading digit $1$. If $S\subseteq A\subseteq\mathbb N$, and if the (natural) density of $A$ exists, then the density of $A$ must be equal to $1$. It follows that $S$ can't be the intersection of a finite number of sets whose densities exist.

(Let $d$ be the density of $A$. To see that $d=1$, choose $n$ sufficiently large that the density of $A$ on the interval $[1,\ 10^n]$ and the density of $A$ on the interval $[1,\ 2\cdot10^n]$ are approximately equal to $d$; then $d\approx\frac{d+1}2$ so $d\approx1$.)

Likewise, a subset of $S$ whose density exists must have density zero, so $S$ can't be the union of a finite number of sets whose densities exist.